# How to automate executing stored procedure in SSIS with random parameters and output to a CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a stored procedure called `sp1` to generate random parameters for another stored procedure called `sp2`, and `sp1` uses output parameters and it can output three parameters which are `p1`, `p2`,and `p3` and `sp2` uses these three parameters to get executed.

So, how should I execute the `sp2` in SSIS using random parameters and output the results to CSV files?

Answer (score 2):

First use an Execute SQL task to execute sp1.  Use SSIS variables to hold the output parameter values of sp1.

Then use a Data Flow Task with sp2 as the Source Component query, and use the same variables as input parameters of sp2.

Comment: Could you explain more? I just get started to learn SSIS and don't know exactly which task to use, thanks